# How to create a new column with the total sum of row values in P

Tags: python, pandas

I have an interesting project and I have become stuck with a crucial part of the data scrubbing: I don't know how to create a total column based on the values of a specific rows/columns

My dataframe has this information:

```
CustomerID ActivityType
01134A       Email
01134B       Email
01134A       Call
01134B       Email
```

My desired output would be

```
 CustomerID ActivityType TotalEmail TotalCall
01134A       Email         1           1
01134B       Email         2           0
01134A       Call          1           1
01134B       Email         2           0
```

I have tried

```
df['EmailTotal']='df.groupby('ActivityType'=='Email').transform('sum')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) with [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) and for change columns names add [`DataFrame.add_prefix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html):

```
df = df.join(pd.crosstab(df.CustomerID, df.ActivityType).add_prefix('Total'), on='CustomerID')
print (df)
  CustomerID ActivityType  TotalCall  TotalEmail
0     01134A        Email          1           1
1     01134B        Email          0           2
2     01134A         Call          1           1
3     01134B        Email          0           2
```

EDIT:

Your solution should be changed with comparing, converting to integers and grouoping by Series `df.CustomerID` with `transform` and `sum`:

```
df['ETotal']=df.ActivityType.eq('Email').astype(int).groupby(df.CustomerID).transform('sum')
df['CTotal']= f.ActivityType.eq('Call').astype(int).groupby(df.CustomerID).transform('sum')
```

Comment: Even if i'm not the OP. Thank you for the straight solution, did not know crosstab :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should read group by documentation :)

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html

Group By will group by each unique value ou unique combination of values given in the key columns.

YourDataFrame.groupby("ActivityType") will create in memory a kind of dataframe for each ActivityType value, you cannot see the data structure like that.

You now need to apply your agg function(in our case), you want a sum, then simply apply sum :)

YourDataFrame.groupby("ActivityType").sum() will give you the sum for each group.

Up to you if you want to pivot after that step :)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the aggregation in 2 separate Dataframes and then merge them with the parent Dataframe
for instance

```
total = df.groupby('CustomerID', 'ActivityType').agg({'count':df.ActivityType}).reset_index()(columns={'count':'ActivityType'})
emailtotal=total['ActivityType' == 'Email'].rename(columns={'ActivityType':'TotalEmail'})
calltotal=total['count_ActivityType' == 'Call'].rename(columns={'ActivityType':'TotalCall'})

final= pd.join([df,emailtotal,calltotal], on=['CustomerID', 'ActivityType'], how='inner')
final.head()
  CustomerID ActivityType  TotalCall  TotalEmail
0     01134A        Email          1           1
1     01134B        Email          0           2
2     01134A         Call          1           1
3     01134B        Email          0           2
```